# The usage of 比べて -- without saying the thing being compared to?

Tags: grammar, translation, usage, particles, english-to-japanese

I want to express: 'He is good at basketball. In comparison, she is less skilled.'

My sentence is: 彼はバスケットボールで上手です。彼女は、比べて、下手です。

Is this correct? Please correct me for any errors I've made

皆さま回答よろしくお願いしますm(_ _)m

Answer (score 2):

「比べて」 can't stand alone. You could use 「それに比べると」, as in...

> 彼はバスケットボール**が**[上手]{じょうず}です。彼女は、**それに比べると**、｛[上手]{じょうず}ではありません。/ [上手]{うま}くありません。｝

<sub>それに比べて would be grammatically correct, but それに比べて、彼女は下手です。/ 上手ではありません。 would sound like "In contrast / Unlike him, she is unskilled/poor.")</sub>